# limit of $ \begin{equation} a_n = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{n} & \text{if } n\ne100\\ 1000& \text{if } n=1000 \end{cases} \end{equation}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

limit of $ \begin{equation}
a_n =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n} & \text{if } n\ne100\\
1000& \text{if } n=1000
\end{cases}
\end{equation}$

My first thought was if we take $N$ large enough the series would converge; 
But then I remembered the $\epsilon-Definition$ and if we take $\epsilon=0.5$ it would mean that $\forall$ $n>2$ the distance to $0$ would be smaller than $0.5$ which is obviously not the case...

On the other hand every subsequnce has to converge to the same limit, as for n=100 i do have another subsequence which doesnt converge to 0. Am i right with my thought ?

Comment: For $\epsilon=0.5$ why do you need $n>2$? You should rather take $n>100$ and see that the definition works fine.

Comment: Always remember that changing the values of sequence at a finite number of points (indices) does not alter the limiting behaviour of the sequence.

Comment: Also don't use equation or cases in your title.

Comment: thank you, i think the key part is that taking finitely number of points does not change the limit

Comment: There must be a typo in the definition of $a_n$. As written it says $a_{1000} = 1000$ and also $a_{1000} = 1/1000$ (the second because $n=1000\ne100$.

Answer (score 1):

If $ \epsilon >0$ is given, then we have:

$|a_n-0|=\frac{1}{n}< \epsilon$ if $n > \max\{\frac{1}{\epsilon}, 100\}$

Hence $a_n \to 0.$

Comment: Ah thanks, but isn't $a_{100}$ a subsequence which does not converge to 0 ?

Comment: No. $a_{100}$ is not a subsequence. Recall the definition ! https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subsequence.html

Comment: does a subsequence need to have infinitely points to ?